# Hello OpenCV Android

Tags: android

I'm trying the tutorial located [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)

I have compiled sample code for openCV without issues -  so I'm sure I have all the necessary things installed for opencv. I've added the opencv library to my project and I'm compiling with java 1.6 (java 7 doesn't work with opencv4android right now AFAIK). I added the opencv library as a resource as well.

However, the sample code doesn't make sense to me once it gets to step 5 under Hello OpenCV example.

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mView = new HelloOpenCVView(this);
     setContentView (mView);
}
```

Is the code I'm talking about, I immediately get the error "mView cannot be resolved to a variable". mview is consistently used without declaration throughout the code -- is it from another file I'm supposed to be importing? Any ideas? Thanks
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "m" in `mView` indicates that it is a member variable. It's a language naming convention used in most Android apps (you can read more about it [here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions) if you feel so inclined). So just add the following inside MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements HelperCallbackInterface
{
    private HelloOpenCVView mView;

    ... // rest of class
}
```

That should resolve your `mView cannot be resolved to a variable` error, which is just a scoping issue.

On that page it says to refer to the `15-puzzle` sample for more details. I suggest taking a look at it [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/15-puzzle/src/org/opencv/samples/puzzle15/Puzzle15Activity.java).

I agree it is a little confusing. Since OpenCV is open source, feel free to send them a GitHub pull request with an amendment to this part of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately can't upvote you because of my lack of reputation, but you're definitely correct. The rest of the problems were solved just by adding a bunch of imports. It also seems that they might as well include the full import list in addition to the entirety of the manifest (I didn't define main at first), but either way, thanks for the help!